# In content management system, How do I display contents(text includes codes) without executing them on html page?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm creating a content management system for blogging for a project.When creating new post using TinyMCE text editor if we insert texts with some images codes(html,javascript,php) to the database, How do I display them after fetching from database without executing those code on html page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write a custom parser to parse your text. That way you can decide to keep which HTML tags. For beginning, you can consider using this https://github.com/paquettg/php-html-parser (So we don't have to reinvent the wheels)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at : http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

`htmlspecialchars` function converts special chars (such as < >) to HTML entities (such as &br; &nbsp). So browser will not execute as HTML code but it will display special chars.